# Streaming data from Mongoose - "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an app that's using Node, Express, Angular, and Mongoose.  I'm trying to get a very large dataset out of MongoDB so I'm trying to stream it.  It loads the first chunk of data but then I get an error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.  Below is my code.

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var Org  = require('./models/org');
  var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
  var stringify = require('stringify');
  app.get('/api/orgs', function(req, res){ 
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        Org.find().stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res); 

        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      })
    };
```

**models/org.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Org', new Schema({
    ein : {type : Number},
}), 'irs9902013');
```

Comment: you are doing it correct i guess. Just one change i would like you to do. make it `res.json(doc)` . Not sure what is data variable there.

Comment: that was typo, it says "doc" in my actual code, it's definitely not correct, @c.P.u1 is definitely right about the headers being sent multiple times

Comment: The request handler for `app.get('/api/orgs')` is nested inside the handler for `app.get('/api/models')` . You'll need to move that out

Comment: That was mistake from just adding the rest of my code instead of copying it.  I've copied it now, they weren't nested in my actual code

Comment: should i just make this a different question?

Comment: You are not connecting to mongodb in `models/org.js`. `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/databaseName')`.

Comment: it is connected, i just have that in another file.  I could post the entire thing but it's pretty big.  the mongod console also shows me that i'm connected

Comment: nevermind, it's just taking forever to execute.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the streaming interface, the `data` event is emitted for every document in the query result. This is resulting in `res.json(data)` being called multiple times, which is an error since `res.json` internally invokes `res.send` which tries to set the charset on the `Content-Type` header. Since the first document is already written to the response body, trying to set a header after that is not possible.

You can directly pipe the query results to the response using `JSONStream` as:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
Model.find().stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

A naive way to do it would be to accumulate the documents from the `data` event and wait for the `end` event to call `res.json(accumulatedDocuments)`, but this defeats the purpose of streaming and can be directly done using

```
Model.find().toArray(function (err, results) {
  res.json(results);
});
```

Comment: is there a package i need to add to get the first method to work?  It's giving me an error where the stringify method begins saying undefined is not a function

Comment: Ah, I was using json-stream.  So I'm not getting any errors but now my query isn't being executed, just to be clear, I want this? 
`app.get('/api/orgs', function(req, res){
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var query = Model.find().stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
query.on('data', function (doc) {

res.json(doc);
}).on('error', function (err) {
// handle the error
console.log(err);
}).on('close', function () {

});
     `

Comment: You no longer need to listen for `data` events, `pipe` will handle that. This is all you need: `app.get('/api/orgs', function(req, res){ res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); Model.find().stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res); })`

Comment: Still won't execute the query. I'm checking the mongod console and nothing happens...

Comment: Does the request handler get executed? Can you add logging around the request handler or post your full code?

Comment: Edited original comment with full code.  Get status 200 headers undefined